# Append to nested Object if exists else create new nested object in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have come across a situation where I need to create a new nested object if it doesn't exists else modify the existing object. Any idea how to do that.

```
const data = await docClient
    .update({
      TableName: DYNAMO_TABLE,
      Key: {
        TaskQueueSid: event.TaskQueueSid,
      },
      UpdateExpression:
        "SET TaskQueueName = :TaskQueueName, Tasks = if_not_exists(Tasks, :empty_object)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":TaskQueueName": event.TaskQueueName,
        ":Tasks": {
          TaskSid: event.TaskSid,
          TaskAssignmentStatus: event.TaskAssignmentStatus
        },
        ":id" : id,
        ":empty_object": {},
      },
    })
    .promise();
```

In the above if `Tasks` doesn't exist in the record, I need to create a new empty object and add the `:Tasks` to it with `:id` as the key. Else if `Tasks` exist in record, just add to `:id` to the existing object. In the above I can create an empty object but I cannot add the `:id => :Tasks` to it. How to achieve that? Thank you.